# Android NDK and .m4

Tags: android, android-ndk, port, m4

There is an OpenSource Linux library that has a file folder with files .m4. I want to port this library on Android NDK. Question: how to compile these. m4? Ie how to write Android.mk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

m4 is a macro language, and these files are written in m4.  You will need to port the m4 program if you wish to run them.  You can learn more about m4 on Stackoverflow by searching on the m4 tag i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/m4